Inject Vavr type in Quarkus
When using a Vavr List for a config property
@ConfigProperty(name = "tags.allowed") // in application.properties: tags.allowed=tag1,tag2
private io.vavr.collection.List<String> allowedTags;

Quarkus fails with
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting io.vavr.collection.List<java.lang.String>

Is it somehow possible to configure Quarkus so it knows how to construct custom types list a Vavr List?
I tried it with
@Produces
<T> List<T> vavrList(T value) {
  return List.of(value);
}

and
@Produces
<T> List<T> vavrList(T... values) {
  return List.of(values);
}

and (comparable to a Spring example for same issue)
@Produces
List<String> vavrList(java.util.List<String> jul) {
  return List.ofAll(jul);
}

but these never get called.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624577/how-to-use-configproperties-with-a-converter-class
